# My Photos & Camera storage decreased drastically, but how?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, photos.app

Photos & Camera took up somewhere around 2.5 GB of storage a week ago. I check now and it is at 700 MB. Does anyone how this is possible?

I remember having the option that makes a small video of each picture taken, turned on, and turning it off for each photo that I had stored. That did not reduce the storage of my Photos immediately, perhaps it updated just now? However, when I go to my Photos I still see the option to turn it on for my photos. I think this is weird: I turn it off for my photos but for some reason it is still available to be turned on at my photos?

Photos and Videos is now 1.1 GB on my iCloud: more size taken up than on my iPhone. I also remember turning on the option 'Optimise iPhone Storage' for my photos, but this did not change the size of my Photos storage immediately either at that time.

Anyone who has a clue how the size of my Photos and Videos on my iPhone SE suddenly decreased from 2.5 to 0.7 GB? Is it the change of a setting that takes a while to kick in?

Kind regards

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Answer (score 1):

The "Optimize [device] storage" setting, associated with iCloud Photo Library does not work instantly, so it may explain the behavior you describe. It needs to upload your originals to iCloud and then it may kick in only if you seem to need space on your device.

From an [article on Macworld](https://www.google.cl/amp/www.macworld.com/article/3039938/data-center-cloud/the-problem-with-optimize-iphone-storage-and-other-cloud-services.amp.html):

> If you take a photo with your iPhone (or other iOS device) camera, iOS doesn’t downsample or optimize images or video until it’s uploaded it to iCloud Photo Library and the storage is needed on the iOS device.